# Button with two right arrows

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

What I need is to implement button with two right arrows. One arrow to cut piece of left side of button and one arrow to extend right side of button (please see attached image).

[image]

What I succeed for now is only to add right arrow (see image below).

[image]

Below is current css that I have.

```css
  .arrow-button {
    width: 178px;
    height: 82px;
    position: relative;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #be1a20;
  }
  .arrow-button:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 26px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left: 13px solid #be1a20;
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
 }
 
 .arrow-label {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .layer {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="arrow-button">
        <div class="row">
          <label class="arrow-label">
            SENT
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <label class="layer">
            10
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can we assume the background color is always the same?

Comment: @Roberrrt yup always same.

Comment: In that case, @dfsq already answered us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with gradient without the need of extra markup or pseudo-element. You will be able to have transparency also:

```css
.button {
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 display:inline-flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 padding:0 30px;
 color:#fff;
 background:
 linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%,red 50.5%) right calc(50% - 10px) /30px 20px no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%,red 50.5%) right calc(50% + 10px) /30px 20px no-repeat,
 
 linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%,red 50.5%) left calc(50% + 10px) /30px 20px no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%,red 50.5%) left calc(50% - 10px) /30px 20px no-repeat,
 
 linear-gradient(red,red) bottom left/30px calc(50% - 20px) no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(red,red) top left/30px calc(50% - 20px) no-repeat,
 linear-gradient(red,red) center/calc(100% - 60px) 100% no-repeat;
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  some content
</div>
```

You can also make this dynamic by using CSS variables:

```css
.button {
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 display:inline-flex;
 color:#fff;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 margin:5px;
 --w:30px;
 --h:20px;
 padding:0 var(--w);
 background:
 linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50%,red 50.5%) right calc(50% - var(--h)/2) /var(--w) var(--h),
 linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%,red 50.5%) right calc(50% + var(--h)/2) /var(--w) var(--h),
 
 linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%,red 50.5%) left calc(50% + var(--h)/2) /var(--w) var(--h),
 linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%,red 50.5%) left calc(50% - var(--h)/2) /var(--w) var(--h),
 
 linear-gradient(red,red) bottom left/var(--w) calc(50% - var(--h)),
 linear-gradient(red,red) top left/var(--w) calc(50% - var(--h)),
 linear-gradient(red,red) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--w)) 100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  Some content
</div>

<div class="button" style="width:80px;--w:20px;--h:20px;">
  Some content
</div>

<div class="button" style="width:120px;--w:40px;--h:20px;">
  Some content  
</div>
<div class="button" style="height:50px;--w:10px;--h:10px;">
  Some content
</div>
```

Comment: In Chrome (66.0.3359.181) these seem to have a lot of lines going through and around the arrow on the left.

Comment: @Stewartside because gradient arent anti-aliasing ;) .. to avoid this you can increase the % of color stop .. you can try 51% instead of 50.5%

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 5):

Similar what you did with right arrow, use :before and :after:

```css
.arrow-button {
  width: 178px;
  height: 82px;
  position: relative;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #be1a20;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.arrow-button:before,
.arrow-button:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 26px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 13px solid transparent;
  border-left: 13px solid white;
  border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
}

.arrow-button:after {
  left: 100%;
  border-left: 13px solid #be1a20;
}

.arrow-label {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
}

.layer {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-button">
  <div class="row">
    <label class="arrow-label">SENT</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <label class="layer">10</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the only difference right arrow from the left is `left` and `border-left` styles you need to redefine:

```
.arrow-button:after {
  left: 100%;
  border-left: 13px solid #be1a20;
}
```

Note, I vertical-aligned text with flexbox but you don't have to do it this way, this is not relevant to arrows.

Comment: thanks a lot!! How did i missed that i can do it with after... :) Note: aligning is even better thanks for that too!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```css
  .arrow-button {
    width: 178px;
    height: 82px;
    position: relative;
    object-fit: contain;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #be1a20;
  }
  .arrow-button:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 26px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left: 13px solid white;
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
 }
 .arrow-button:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 26px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left: 13px solid #be1a20;
    border-bottom: 13px solid transparent;
 }
 .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-direction:column;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: inherit;
 }
 .arrow-label {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .layer {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="arrow-button">
        <div class="container">
          <label class="arrow-label">
            SENT
          </label>
          <label class="layer">
            10
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
```